# SaveasFile Outlook mail function giving me error giving : acess denied you dont have permission for this operation

Tags: python, win32com

So what am i trying to do is basically, save an attachment. That is on a specific email. With a specific date on it, but when i try to execute the SaveasFile method. I get an error. `(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Not possible to save attachment. You dont have the permission to execute this operation.', None, 0, -2147024891), None)`

My base code is as follows.

```
path_zip = "../Query/Full_prod"  #localizacao onde fica a file zipada

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')# Abre o outlook

mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") #Call do outlook

root_folder = mapi.Folders.Item(1) # Folder inicial do seu outlook

subfolder = root_folder.Folders['Eventtracks bot prod'] # Subfolder do local arquivado

messages = subfolder.Items


def SalvaAnexo(): # Retorna os anexos que nao estao sendo salvos.
    created_files = os.listdir(f'{path_zip}/Marco') #Mes desejado
    created_files = [i[3:5] for i in created_files] # Dias ja criados
    for message in messages: 
        if "2022-03" in message.Subject: # Filtro para diminuir tamanho do loop
                attachments = message.Attachments
                attachment = attachments.Item(1) #Pegando o attachment
                dias_email = str(message.Subject.split("-")[-1]) #Dia dos attachment
                if dias_email not in created_files:
                    print(dias_email)
                    attachment.SaveasFile(r'E:\csms\Query\Full_prod')
```

Is worth noting that before hand i used this function on my C: drive and this little function worked perfectly. Would apreciate some help.

Comment: Looks like you have permission issues, Is the script being run as administrator and do you have write access to the `E:` drive?

Comment: I am pretty sure i do but how could i guarantee it?. And not it is not being run as admin

Comment: run this and check if you get `True`  
`os.access(YOUR_DRIVE_HERE, os.X_OK | ox.W_OK)`
Make sure you `import os` before though.

Comment: It gave me true answer

Comment: Oh, that's weird, I guess there's some sort of issue with outlook then.

Comment: `attachment.SaveasFile` where's the filename, Looks like you're trying to save in a directory, but there's no filename

Comment: Cant believe it was something as stupid as that. Didnt even notice got to stuck to the permission denied error. Thank you for help